# Расширения Google

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, автоматизация, puppeteer, google-extensions

Такая задача, мне нужно сделать расширение для автоматизации браузера, нужно именно расширение. Нажми туда, подожди столько то, ввести такие то данные. Пожалуйста, подскажите, с помощью чего можно сделать такую работу ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полагаю, что вы хотите сделать расширение для браузера? Возьмем для примера расширение для Google Chrome.

Для начала вам понадобится файл с расширением `.json`, а именно `manifest.json`, в котором будут прописаны параметры для вашего расширения.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "application-name",
  "description": "description of the application",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "logo.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab"]
}
```

Где `default_icon`, это логотип вашего расширения. На данный момент Google Chrome поддерживает исключительно `.png` формат.

Где `default_popup` это ваш дропдаун меню. Обычно это `html` файл, в котором вы будете задавать внешний вид дропдаун меню для своего Google Chrome расширения. Сам принцип работы с HTML файлом остается стандартным. В него также можно импортировать JavaScript скрипты, тем самым добавив программную логику для дальнейшего управления браузером.

После того, как вы создадали `manifest.json` файл с настройками для вашего приложения, а также сделади внешний вид с помощью HTML файла, добавив программную логику в него с помощью JavaScript файла. Вам нужно лишь загрузить собственное расширение в сам браузер. Для этого введите `chrome://extensions/` в URL поле вашего браузера Google Chrome, перетащите все файлы в меню расширений, а затем перезагрузите браузер. Ваше расширение для браузера готово к использованию! Теперь вы можете выбрать его в меню расширений, а также закрепить его на панели своего браузера.